# Finding the sum of n big numbers

Tags: c++, arrays

Question: Given a number k, find the sum of k positive big integers.
This is my code,it works, but our Online Judge is rejecting it, says segfault. Why does it show segfault? I could do it with two strings but why isn't this working?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void add(int l,int k);

void append(char a[], int temp);

int o;

int tf=0;

int carry=0;

char b[1000000];

char a[10000][10000];

char c[1000000];

int main()
{
    int k,x=0,l=0,m=0;
    cin>>k;
    while(x<k)
    {
        cin>>a[x];
        if(strlen(a[x])>l)
        {
            l=strlen(a[x]);
        }
        x++;
    }
    x=0;
    while(x<k)
    {
        if(strlen(a[x])<l)
        {
            int temp=0;
            append(a[x],l-strlen(a[x]));
        }
        x++;
    }
    add(l,k);
    if(carry!=0)
    {
        cout<<carry;
    }
    while(o>=0)
    {
        cout<<(int)b[o];
        o--;
    }
}

void add(int l,int k)
{
    int lb=l-1;
    int r=k-1;
    int sum=0;
    int x=0;
    int neg=0;
    while(lb>=0)
    {
        r=k-1;
        sum=0;
        while(r>=0)
        {
            sum=sum+a[r][lb]-48;
            r--;
        }
        sum=sum+carry;
        lb--;
        if(sum>=10)
        {
            b[x]=sum%10;
            carry=sum/10;
        }
        else
        {
            b[x]=sum;
            carry=0;
        }
        sum=0;
        o=x;
        x++;
    }
}

void append(char a[], int temp)
{
    int l=0,m;
    int tempb=temp;
    m=strlen(a)-1;
    while(temp>0)
    {
        c[l]='0';
        l++;
        temp--;
    }
    int z=0;
    while(z<=m)
    {
        c[l]=a[z];
        z++;
        l++;
    }
    z=0;
    while(z<=m+tempb)
    {
        a[z]=c[z];
        z++;
    }
}
```

Input Format:
First line contains k , which specifies the number of big numbers. Each of the next k lines contains a
big positive integer.
Output Format:
For each test case print the new big integer in a new line

```
Sample Input:
3
1331331
1313
453535322
Sample Output:
454867966

Constraints:
1<=k<=10
1<=number of digits in big numbers<=10000
```

Comment: since you are dealing with numbers, why do u need a 2d character array 'a'??

Comment: @Nandu well, he could do it with strings...

Comment: It just means your judge used a test case that pushes limits in a way your test case did not - presumably a much bigger value

Comment: Seg faults could be caused by buffer overruns. Try using a bounds-checked data structure to track down the error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the problem statement:

- Each input entry my have at most n<sub>max</sub> = 10000 digits
- Since each entry is stored as a C-style, zero-terminated string, each character array must have a length of (n<sub>max</sub> + 1) = 10001 characters, to accomodate for the C-string terminator '\0'.

As you stored the entries into character arrays without leaving room for the zero terminator, assuming each entry was 10000-characters long:

- Each entry with k>=1 overwrote the terminator or entry k-1, thus coalescing the entries together;
- You thus ended with one giant string, with l = strlen(a[0]) = 100000;
- From then on, all further processings were performed with these incorrect (coalesced) inputs and length, leading to buffer overrun at some point later in the execution.

Comment: Turns out the constraints were wrong. They fixed the problem.